# htaccess perpetually ignored by Apache on MacOS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up a PHP project locally on my Mac but I can't for the life of me get Apache to stop ignoring the .htaccess file.

I have edited the apache2/httpd.conf file to enable mod_rewrite.so and set Override All instead of Override None here, as instructed by the internet:

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
#
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All 
</Directory>
```

Supposedly after restarting Apache this should get it to work 100% of the time, but no.

I placed the site files in Desktop/projectname - do I need to place it somewhere else? This is procedural PHP. I have some Laravel projects placed in the Desktop directory and they all worked out of the box with no need to meddle with system configuration files.

PHP version is 7.2 if that matters, which it shouldn't.

I have spent 3 hours bashing my head with this.

Comment: Thanks, but where in the output of phpinfo() am I supposed to look? That thing is huge.

Comment: Made the change, restarted apache - still htaccess is ignored.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Before all that, can you tell me where to find the virtualhost configuration file for the project?

Comment: It's not, I tried searching earlier but the sites-enabled folder doesn't exist

Comment: Look at your Apache configuration, make sure this line is not commented out `AccessFileName .htaccess`

Comment: @Nic3500 That line doesn't exist at all in the file. But the default value is .htaccess so that should be fine

Comment: If the configuration is not present, I am not sure it will do anything, and the doc does not specify.  Try it out!

Comment: @Nic3500 tried it, didn't help. I'm really losing it here, it's been 3 days and this nonsense is blocking my project